# How to animate background image HUE or SATURATION repeatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, i have background image (png) on my homepage.

Is it possible to animate HUE or SATURATION of an image, to change from -90 to +90 value, going repeatable (infinite)? With jQuery or javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305362/colour-saturation-desat-in-jquery

Comment: Try this linke perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143227/jquery-change-hue-saturation-gamma-of-img